Robust way to escape a bash variable for using it in "awk -v var=..." assignment
I'm looking for a robust way to pass a bash variable to awk through -v so that the resulting awk variable would exactly contain the string in the bash variable.
Example:
#!/bin/bash

b='dir\t\010\out'

awk -v a="$b" 'BEGIN{print a}'

Expected output:
dir\t\010\out

My guess is that doubling the backslashes should be enough, but I can't say it's still true for any string. Any idea?

The question's been closed before I could post an answer to it...
While using ENVIRON is the simplest method, here's how you can escape a bash variable for passing it as a literal string through -v to any POSIX awk:
#!/bin/bash

awk_esc() {
    local v="${1//\\/\\\\}"
    printf %s "${v//$'\n'/\\n}"
}

b='A\t
B'

awk -v a="$(awk_esc "$b")" 'BEGIN{print a}'

A\t
B


See also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13808909/should-awk-expand-escape-sequences-in-command-line-assigned-variables

See How do I use shell variables in an awk script?.

Dragons be there. Use the environment like in oguz ismail's answer.   With -v, you're not only worrying about shell escaping, but the fact that Awk interprets the argument as Awk string literal syntax: so for instance the two-character sequence \n becomes a newline character.

You can pass it as an environment variable.
$ bash_var='dir\t\010\out'
$ bash_var=$bash_var awk 'BEGIN { awk_var = ENVIRON["bash_var"]; print awk_var }'
dir\t\010\out


It seems like the way to go, +1

apparently the ENVIRON approach even allows even shell arrays to be passed in full (but awk sees it as a single string not an array)
I tested the zsh shell-generated array called signals :
signals=( EXIT HUP INT QUIT ILL TRAP ABRT EMT FPE KILL BUS SEGV 
          SYS PIPE ALRM TERM URG STOP TSTP CONT CHLD TTIN TTOU
          IO XCPU XFSZ VTALRM PROF WINCH INFO USR1 USR2 ZERR DEBUG )


__=$signals [m/g/n]awk 'BEGIN { print ENVIRON["__"] }'


EXIT HUP INT QUIT ILL TRAP ABRT EMT FPE KILL BUS SEGV
SYS PIPE ALRM TERM URG STOP TSTP CONT CHLD TTIN TTOU
IO XCPU XFSZ VTALRM PROF WINCH INFO USR1 USR2 ZERR DEBUG


Yes, to output a backslash you would type \\. The code could then look something like:
EDIT2
#!/bin/bash
bash_var='dir\t\010\out'
awk -v awk_var="${bash_var//\\/\\\\}" 'BEGIN{ print awk_var }'


I think the point is that they don't control how bash_var is created, they want to make it correct when passing it to awk.

@Barmar That's right; bash_var comes from an argument to the script.

According to the POSIX specification of awk, you'll also need to replace the raw LFs with \n when passing them through -v. Here's what I get when I don't do it on UNIX: awk -v v=$'\n' 'BEGIN{print v}' awk: file "(null)": line 1: Newline in string

@Fravadona Which version of awk do you use ? I don't get that error with awk/Ubuntu.

@Philippe This error message is from the POSIX awk of Solaris; but it's not the only one, I get similar errors on macOS, FreeBSD and AIX
